# Angular - Using Mat Paginator, how can I remove the background color on page buttons?

Tags: css, angular, pagination, angular-material

**Code Example**

```
<mat-paginator style-paginator showFirstLastButtons [showTotalPages]="3" [refreshButtons]="dataSource.data.length" [length]="dataSource.data.length" [pageSizeOptions]="[15, 30, 45, 60]">
                    </mat-paginator>
```

**Preview Example**

[image]

What I want, is to remove the grey background around the buttons?
I assume it may be done via `::ng-deep` somehow but not sure.

Thank you, and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this style in your css/scss.

```
::ng-deep .mat-paginator .mat-icon-button{
   background-color: unset;
}
```

you can also set the background-color to your desired color (i.e. the color of the background)